# SignalR- Unable to create proxy as it throws uncaught typeerror in the browser console

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, signalr

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC application where I am using signalR for real time database notifications 
I am trying to create a proxy using the following script

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>JobStatus</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            // Proxy created on the fly
            var job = $.connection.jobHub;

            // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
            job.client.displayStatus = function () {
                getData();
            };

            // Start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start();
            getData();
        });

        function getData() {
            var $tbl = $('#tblJobInfo');
            $.ajax({
                url: '../JobInfo/',
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $tbl.empty();
                        $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Executed Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>');
                        var rows = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].JobID + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].LastExecutionDate.toString().substr(0,10) + '</td><td>' + data[i].Status + '</td></tr>');
                        }
                        $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="tblJobInfo" style="text-align:center;margin-left:10px"></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my SignalR Hub class is as follows

```
public class JobHub : Hub
    {
        public static void Show()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JobHub>();
            context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
        }
    }
```

but for some reason when I go to my view on the browser and look at the console it throws me follwing error

```
TypeError: $.connection is undefined    

var job = $.connection.jobHub;
```

**Not sure how to deal with this**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if:

```
~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js
```

is available and loading correctly

You can also reference it from cdn:

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.0.1.min.js
```

Comment: you are right it is not but I tried clearing some cache and reinstall the SignalR framework and it is loading now